# Hide Last Row not hiding from form submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am attempting to write a script that on form submit will send two sets of data to two different spreadsheets. The data is derived from one form. It is supposed to copy the most recent entry and then hide the row to prevent duplication. I am finding that on some occasions it is not hiding the last row and multiple copies are being copied. I realize my script is probably not the most efficient, for example, I could not get a range to work!

The sleep utilities were inserted as I thought there may have been a delay in the writing of the form's input to the spreadsheet and the script was running before this was complete.

The script is attached to the form which writes to a Form Responses sheet, this is then split to a company spreadsheet and a customer spreadsheet. Well that is the intention anyway!

```
function copyRow(){

    Utilities.sleep(2000)

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1_pnsvWtqB4CUivQZE65nFR0AG9zTOgqBVSlPZW4YCUQ'); //Source Form Input
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Responses');
    var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
    var rowIdx = sheet.getLastRow();
    var rowValues = sheet.getRange(lastrow,1,1,74).getValues();
    Logger.log(rowValues);

    Utilities.sleep(5000)

    var destValues = []; //Data to AUSJET
    destValues.push(rowValues[0][0],rowValues[0][1],rowValues[0][2],rowValues[0][3],rowValues[0][4],rowValues[0][5],rowValues[0][6],rowValues[0][7]
                     ,rowValues[0][8],rowValues[0][9],rowValues[0][10],rowValues[0][11],rowValues[0][12],rowValues[0][13],rowValues[0][14],rowValues[0][15]
                     ,rowValues[0][16],rowValues[0][17],rowValues[0][18],rowValues[0][19],rowValues[0][20],rowValues[0][21],rowValues[0][22],rowValues[0][23]
                     ,rowValues[0][24],rowValues[0][25],rowValues[0][26],rowValues[0][27],rowValues[0][28],rowValues[0][29],rowValues[0][30],rowValues[0][31]
                     ,rowValues[0][32],rowValues[0][33],rowValues[0][34],rowValues[0][35],rowValues[0][36],rowValues[0][37],rowValues[0][38],rowValues[0][39]
                     ,rowValues[0][40],rowValues[0][41],rowValues[0][42],rowValues[0][43],rowValues[0][44],rowValues[0][45],rowValues[0][46],rowValues[0][47]
                     ,rowValues[0][48],rowValues[0][49],rowValues[0][50],rowValues[0][51],rowValues[0][52],rowValues[0][53],rowValues[0][54],rowValues[0][55]
                     ,rowValues[0][56],rowValues[0][57],rowValues[0][58],rowValues[0][59],rowValues[0][60],rowValues[0][61],rowValues[0][62],rowValues[0][63]
                     ,rowValues[0][64],rowValues[0][65],rowValues[0][66],rowValues[0][67],rowValues[0][68],rowValues[0][69],rowValues[0][70],rowValues[0][71]
                     ,rowValues[0][73],rowValues[0][74]);
    // copy data from col A to col BU


    var dest = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1KQ43DJsJY0RpSnFHDcVfgAWLRfLKE6OD28CFkbjpJoU').getSheetByName('Form Responses');[1];
    dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,destValues.length).setValues([destValues]);

    var destValues = []; //DATA to CONCATENATOR
    destValues.push(rowValues[0][0],rowValues[0][1],rowValues[0][2],rowValues[0][3],rowValues[0][4],rowValues[0][5],rowValues[0][6],rowValues[0][7]
                     ,rowValues[0][8],rowValues[0][9],rowValues[0][10],rowValues[0][11],rowValues[0][12],rowValues[0][13],rowValues[0][14],rowValues[0][15]
                     ,rowValues[0][16],rowValues[0][17],rowValues[0][18],rowValues[0][19],rowValues[0][20],rowValues[0][21],rowValues[0][22],rowValues[0][23]
                     ,rowValues[0][24],rowValues[0][25],rowValues[0][26],rowValues[0][27],rowValues[0][28],rowValues[0][29],rowValues[0][30],rowValues[0][31]
                     ,rowValues[0][32],rowValues[0][33],rowValues[0][34],rowValues[0][35],rowValues[0][36],rowValues[0][37],rowValues[0][38],rowValues[0][39]
                     ,rowValues[0][40],rowValues[0][41],rowValues[0][42],rowValues[0][43],rowValues[0][44],rowValues[0][45],rowValues[0][46],rowValues[0][47]
                     ,rowValues[0][48],rowValues[0][49],rowValues[0][50],rowValues[0][51],rowValues[0][52],rowValues[0][53],rowValues[0][54],rowValues[0][55]
                     ,rowValues[0][56],rowValues[0][57],rowValues[0][58],rowValues[0][59]);
    // copy data from col A to col BH

    var dest = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1qB4OnKF3-OXFR1kR3jewHgYeslLdmIiE3maQNx0MPbk').getSheetByName('ROAMES');[1];//
    dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,destValues.length).setValues([destValues]);

    Utilities.sleep(2000)

    sheet.hideRows(lastrow)
```

Comment: You have set lastrow as: "var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();", instead it needs to be: "var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();" ??

Comment: Even if you are hiding the row at the end after copying the values, but at the start of the script (that is at the time of getting values) you aren't checking whether the row is already hidden or not? And to get the hidden status of the row is still not possible, have a look at this [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=195).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, that as the data is coming from the form so the first column will be 'Timestamp'.
So, I have copied the last row from the source spreadsheet and then compared the value of column A of this last row with the value of column A of the last row of Destination sheet, if both matches then I haven't copied the data...
Only thing that may cause an issue here is if two or more responses are submitted exactly at a same time
Try the following code:

```
function copyRow(){
  Utilities.sleep(2000);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1_pnsvWtqB4CUivQZE65nFR0AG9zTOgqBVSlPZW4YCUQ');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Responses');
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var destValues = sheet.getRange('A'+lastrow+':BU'+lastrow).getValues();
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1KQ43DJsJY0RpSnFHDcVfgAWLRfLKE6OD28CFkbjpJoU').getSheetByName('Form Responses')
  if( dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow(), 1,1,1).getValue().toString() != destValues[0][0].toString() )
    dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,destValues[0].length).setValues(destValues);

  var destValues = sheet.getRange('A'+lastrow+':BH'+lastrow).getValues();
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1qB4OnKF3-OXFR1kR3jewHgYeslLdmIiE3maQNx0MPbk').getSheetByName('ROAMES')
  if( dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow(), 1,1,1).getValue().toString() != destValues[0][0].toString() )
    dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,destValues[0].length).setValues(destValues);
};
```

Comment: That seems to be working. I'll run a few tests this week. It shouldn't be a problem re multiple responses at once as only three people at any given time will possibly be submitting forms. Thanks Kishan, Andrew.

Comment: Hi Kishan, I am still having trouble with this. Frustratingly, I can't work out the pattern either. Sometimes it copies the two last rows, sometimes it copies the last row only. I have tried a mixture of devices for the form submit (mobile phone vs. PC).  Any more ideas? I am trying to understand your IF statement too.

Comment: In the interim I have used the Scripts Tutorial script for removing a duplicate. I have set the Trigger to go off on formSubmit but with a time delay. In brief testing this has worked......